# Is this possible with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I've purchased a new domain (let's call this domain1.com) and I'd like to use my existing hosting package (let's call this domain0.com) to host the website (powered by Wordpress) - I can re-direct domain1.com to domain0.com/domain1 or domain1.domain0.com.

Is it possible, using .htaccess to do this? Bear in mind that this will be Wordpress-based and so there'll be some extra .htaccess action to get 'pretty permalinks' - will this complicate things even further?

To clarify:

- user enters www.domain1.com
- gets sent to www.domain0.com/domain1/
- htaccess magic makes it look like they are on www.domain1.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is not possible using mod_rewrite only.

Please understand that Apache doesn't do **internal redirect** if HOSTNAME is changing in the target of a RewriteRule. In that case it has to be an **external redirect** using `R` flag. And if there is an **external redirect** then *domain name* of URL in the browser will change to `http://www.domain0.com`.

One possible workaround that you can use is to set the **DOCUMENT_ROOT** for `www.domain1.com` to `domain0_DOCUMENTROOT/domain1`.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your problem then yes you can redirect users like this in **.htaccess**:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://www.domain0.com/domain1.php?req=$1 [QSA,L]
```

also you can redirect user to a special page using .htaccess and then in that special page redirect user wherever you want using php or javascript or anything else.

Comment: Not sure this is what I'm looking for, have clarified my question somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

ok. now i get it .i'm not sure but i think that you cannot redirect a user from a domain to another without address changing! but you can redirect from www.domain1.com to www.domain0.com/domain1 and with .htaccess you can hide "/domain1" at the end of your address. does it helps?